# Coordinate transformations using matrices

Tags: matrices, transformation

I have a coordinate transformation:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r} \rightarrow R \cdot \mathbf{r}
\tag{1}\label{eq:transformation}
\end{equation}

where $R$ is a constant orthogonal matrix. I have been looking through working and can not follow it. I was wondering if some light could be shed. It is stipulated that if \eqref{eq:transformation} then:

\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathbf{r}} \rightarrow R \cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}}
\tag{2}\label{eq:transformeddot}
\end{equation}

is true. Is this always true only is $R$ is orthogonal? Then it states if \eqref{eq:transformation} then \eqref{eq:transformeddot} so that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{r} \cdot R \cdot R^T \cdot \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}^2
\tag{3}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

implying that $|\mathbf{r}| = |\mathbf{r}|$

\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 \rightarrow \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot R \cdot R^T \cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}} = \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2
\tag{4}\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

I am unsure how \eqref{eq:transformeddot} and \eqref{eq:1} are found out. This is all the working out and I am trying to wrap my head around it as opposed to just accepting it. How do I arrive at those equations with more comprehensive mathematics?

**Edit:**

My thought process of obtaining $\mathbf{r}$ follows from \eqref{eq:transformation}:

$\textbf{r}^2 = \textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{r} \rightarrow \textbf{R} \cdot \textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{R} \cdot \textbf{r}$ and I am unsure how I simplify this.

**Remember**

If anyone has the same conundrum remember: $\textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{r} = \textbf{r}^T \textbf{r}$

Comment: please change your notation. Do not use $\Bbb{R}$ for an orthogonal matrix; that is standard notation for the set of real numbers.

Comment: A dot over $r$ means velocity $dr/dt$?

Comment: sorry for that @peek-a-boo that was just the way it was written for me so I copied it across exactly

Comment: yes it does @Winther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some hints:

- $R$ is orthogonal means $RR^T=\mathbf{1}$
- Use the full product rule on such a matrix equation: $\frac{d}{dt} R \cdot r = \frac{dR}{dt} \cdot r + R \frac{dr}{dt}$.

Use these identities in your derivations to get the resulting equations.

To elaborate on the second point, recall a dot product can be represented as $\bf{r} \cdot \bf{r} = \bf{r}^T \bf{r}$, thus after the transformation, the length of the vector is $(R \bf{r})^T (R \bf{r})=\bf{r}^T R^T R \bf{r}$, using the orthogonality property this is nothing but $\bf{r}^T\bf{r}$ which means the vector's magnitude is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I have now reasoned how I obtain the derivative with respect to time but am still stuck with the $\textbf{r}^2$ part.  I have added my thought process to the question. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: @HarrySpratt check my edit, let me know if this helps!

Comment: Ah thank you so much, completely didn't cross my mind that $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}^T \mathbf{r} $